# I can't update the gradle plugin version to 4.1.3

Tags: android, gradle, plugins

My current Gradle plugin version is 4.1.2 and this version working correctly but when I update to 4.1.3 I get this error and I can't build the project:
**Note:I added maven() and jcenter().**

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AndroidCryptography'.
```

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find gradle-4.1.3.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.jar

my build.gradle:

[image]

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and provide a [mcve]. In this case, that would be your project's top-level `build.gradle` file, most likely.

Comment: I think my build.gradle file doesn't have a problem

Comment: In any of your modules' `build.gradle` files (e.g., `app/build.gradle`), do you also have a `buildscript` closure? If so, you might want to check them too. Also, if you click the link in your question to the JAR, does it work? If the answer is no, then there is something about your network that is blocking access to that JAR, as it works from here.

Comment: Can you make sure you have at least the Gradle wrapper 6.5-all?
`https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip`.

You can also try to run in the terminal: `./gradlew app:build -info` and see which error is returning, might give you proper hints to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You Have To Go To -->`gradle-wrapper.properties` and change your gradle version to `6.8.3`

[image: for more info you can load the attached image]

Comment: How do we know what number of plugin tool and what number of gradle version?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the build.gradle(Project) in repositories

google()